# Pandas Datetime Format

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert `01/02/20(Thu)05:05:17` into DD-MM-YYYY format, but struggling through pandas.

```
df['_source.now'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_source.now'])
```

I get this error: `ParserError: Unknown string format: 01/02/20(Thu)05:05:17`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
# day first, use '%d/%m/%y(%a)%H:%M:%S'
# month first, use '%m/%d/%y(%a)%H:%M:%S'
pd.to_datetime(df['_source.now'],format='%m/%d/%y(%a)%H:%M:%S',errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```